# Need help fixing top bar inside another div with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, expand

everybody! I'm trying to create a template as shown in the image below.

I will explain you what it does:

The left and right menus will toggle between 150 and 50 px (I've already made this part of the script using jQuery). When the toggle script runs from 150 to 50, the content of the page will expand (already done that too).

The side menus have "fixed position" written on them in the pictures, but I won't need this anymore because I will use overflow-y: scroll on the content instead of page scroll.

What I don't know how to do: I really can't get that top bar to be fixed and expand the same time content expands.

Image

[image]

Here is what I've done 'till now:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjgNM/73/)

CSS:

```
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
}

#left, #right {
    width: 150px;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

#middle {
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use position fixed for your top bar:

**Html**

```
<div id="top">top bar</div>
```

**Css**

```
#top {position:fixed; background:lightblue; top:0; left:150px; right:150px; }
```

**jQuery**

```
var top = $('#top');
$('#middle').css('padding-top', top.outerHeight());

$('#left').click(function(){
   width = $(this).width();
    if(width == 150){
        $(this).css('width', 50);
        top.css('left', 50);
    } else {
        $(this).css('width', 150);
        top.css('left', 150);
    }
});

$('#right').click(function(){
   width = $(this).width();
    if(width == 150){
        $(this).css('width', 50);
        top.css('right', 50);
    } else {
        $(this).css('width', 150);
        top.css('right', 150);
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AjgNM/80/)

Comment: Working! Thanks, Pete!

Answer (score 0):

I gave the `Top Content div` width `100%' so that it takes its parent width

Modified your code like this.Please see the fiddle.

[WORKING CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/AjgNM/75/)

Comment: This is great, thanks! But there is one problem: the `#content` div will have the `overflow-y: scroll` property, and I want the top bar to stay at the top of the div while scrolling.